# Function that accepts a character and integer n as parameter and displays the next n characters

Tags: python, ascii

> Write a function, which accepts a character and integer n as parameter and display the next n characters.

I have tried something like this but it's still not correct:

```
ch = input("Enter a character :")
n = int(input("How many characters :"))

def characters():
    for i in range(n):
          characters = ch+1
          print(characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just find the ASCII code of the character, add `i`, then convert the code back to a character:

```
characters = chr(ord(ch) + i + 1)
```

also don't forget to call your function at the end of your program:

```
characters()
```

As a side note, don't use the same name for a variable and a function. One will shadow the other.

Comment: can you please show me the whole code. I don't know how to call the function characters()

Comment: This is the whole code. Just add `characters()` as the last line of your code.

Comment: please check I have written the code this way                                                                  
# accept a character from user
ch = input("Enter a character = ")

# accept 'n' as a parameter
n = int(input("How many characters = "))

def characters():
 for i in range(n):
  characters = chr(ord(ch) + i + 1
  print(characters)
characters()
But I am getting a syntax error :
    print(characters)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some code like this

```
def characters(myChar, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(chr(ord(myChar)+i))


ch = input("Enter a character :").upper()
n = int(input("How many characters :"))
characters(ch, n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have changed the code little bit. I have removed that ".upper()" so that I can get both lower case as well as upper case

Comment: you're welcome, of course, my code is just a template you will edit according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you should just define the functions on the upper lines of the code so the dependencies will not mess up.
2. Make sure the function name and variable names don't clash each other (make them unique).

```py
# Define the function for the usecase
def characters(ch, shift):
    # Take the char back to ASCII code and add up the shift, then get back the result in char
    chars = chr(ord(ch) + shift)
    print(chars)


# Get the user input
ch = input("Enter a character :")
n = int(input("How many characters :"))

# Call the function
characters(ch, n)
```

---

#### What if we input z or Z and the shift is positive number?

The answer is you may meet some unprintable characters if there is no any restrictions.

If you restrict that will only alphabets/alphanumerics accepted, you can call it as **Caesar Cipher** which you can explore more in the internet as there are already many explanations and examples out there!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this?

```
def characters(ch,n):
    for i in range(n):
          char = chr(ord(ch) + i + 1)
          print(char)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ch = input("Enter a character :")
    n = int(input("How many characters :"))
    characters(ch,n)
```

Comment: Have you tested this?